# Angular.js delete resource with parameter

Tags: angularjs

My rest api accpets DELETE requests to the following url

```
/api/users/{slug}
```

So by sending delete to a specified user (slug) the user would be deleted. here is the service code:

```
angular.module('UserService',['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource){
    var User = $resource('/api/users/:id1/:action/:id2', //add param to the url
    {}, 
    { 
        delete_user: {
            method: 'DELETE',
            params: {
                id1:"@id"
            }
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            params: {
                id1:"@id"
            }
        }
    }); 

    return User;
});
```

I call the delete function via

```
user.$delete_user({id:user.id}, function(){}, function(response){});
```

However the request seems to be send to the wrong url.

```
/api/users?id=4
```

So the parameter is actually missing, as a result I get a 405 Method not allowed. Is there any chance to send the delete request in the style of my api?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`params` is an object of default request parameteres in your actions. If you want url parameters you have to specify them in the second parameter like this:

```js
angular.module('UserService',['ngResource']).factory('User', function($resource){
    var User = $resource('/api/users/:id1/:action/:id2', //add param to the url
    {id1:'@id'},
    { 
        delete_user: {
            method: 'DELETE'
        }
    }); 

    return User;
});
```

this works with either:

```js
// user has id
user.$delete_user(function(){
  //success
},function(){
  // error
});
```

or

```js
var data = {id:'id_from_data'};
User.delete_user({},data);
```

or

```js
var params = {id1:'id1_from_params'};
User.delete_user(params);
```

I've made a **[plnkr-example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xy366u9Bm9ksXFG33E0L?p=preview)** - you have to open your console to verify that the DELETE requests are correct.

See *parameterDefaults* in the [Angular resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

Comment: I think this is not the problem, I added update function to my question, this works just fine, what you mention are the defaults, they get overriden anyways. However I tried you suggestion and it results in the same problem.

Comment: Yes, `params` in the actions are default parameteres, but not with the '@' keyword. Did you even try my suggestion - because I'm pretty sure it works. If you want to map `{id:123}` to `id1` in `/api/users/:id1` you have to have `{id1:'@id'}` in paramDefaults, not in the action params

Comment: If I use update the route is: /api/users/4?id=4 and it should look exactly the same for delete

Comment: I updated my answer and added a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xy366u9Bm9ksXFG33E0L?p=preview

Comment: Ok this works now, but my other api method "create" does not work, the id is appended to the route, but it should not. How to fix that?

Comment: /api/users/3 [POST] instead of /api/users [POST]

Comment: OK, I've updated the plnkr, read the comments and have a look at the console log - with `method:'POST'` its `user.$update(object_with_params,data_to_send,successFn,errorFn)` - I'm not really sure how to explain this any better than [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28765/discussion-between-artworkad--and-joakimbl)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for a while I was using a service to add / delete / update categories. While passing in params for get it worked fine but then when deleting it was giving me a ?id=1234 instead of api/resource/1234

I got around this by making the default param a string.

///Controller

```
Service.delete({categoryId:id}, function(resp){
  console.log(resp)//whatever logic you want in here 
});
```

//SERVICES

```
$resource('api/resource/:categoryId', {"categoryId":"@categoryId"}, {
   query:{method:"GET"},
   delete:{method:"DELETE"},

});
```

Should work and the resulting url will be, originally I had categoryId in the default params as a variable name.

```
api/resource/1234 etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the '@' in the parameter

```
   .factory('reportFactory', ['$resource', 'baseUrl', function ($resource, baseUrl) {
        return $resource(baseUrl + '/keys/:id', {}, {
        delete: { method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params: {id: 'id'} }
       })
}]);
```

this will give you:

```
  http://localhost:8080/reports/api/keys/b8a8a8e39a8f55da94fdbe6c
```

without the question mark

Comment: I think you need `'@id'` in your params to take the `id` from the resource instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a model, there's no need to add params (params does not work for DELETE anyway):

```
$resource('/users/:id').delete({id: user.id}, function(res) {
  ...
})
```

or

```
$resource('/users/:role/:id').delete({role: 'visitor', id: user.id});
```

I'm not sure if it's a bug of ngResource.