# Rails + Angularjs: How to communicate (delete record from database) with backend?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I stuck on this for the whole day.

On `http://localhost:3001/posts/`, I list all posts I have in the database. I am trying to delete a task with using Angularjs - every loaded record from the database has a link for its deleting:

```
= link_to 'Delete', '', 'ng-click' => "deletePost('#{post.id}')", :id => "post_#{post.id}"
```

Then I have a file `/assets/javascript/angular/controller/posts.js` that looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('AngTestApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/posts/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
        index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
      show:    { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
      update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' }
    });
})

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, Post) {
  $scope.posts = Post.index();
    $scope.deletePost = function(index) {
        console.log("index: "+index);
        post = $scope.posts[index];
      Post.delete(post);
        $scope.posts.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('aa');
    }
})
```

When I click the delete link, I receive this error in the JS console:

```
DELETE http://localhost:3001/posts 404 (Not Found)
```

and in terminal:

```
Started DELETE "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-15 16:23:08 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/posts"):
```

The routes look like this:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

The JS code is very chaotic, I tried to modify a tutorial I found on the Internet, but it doesn't work well.

What is wrong in this attempt?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ID of the record you're trying to delete as a parameter in the call to Rails. Rails is telling you it can't find the route because you do not have an ID.

Since you do not define the DELETE action in your factory, that is likely why the ID is not getting passed. You could also try explicitly passing the id as a param, like below:
$resource takes a params attribute, so you can modify your factory like so:

```
app.factory('Post', function($resource) {
    return $resource("/posts/:id", { id: '@id' }, {
      index:   { method: 'GET', isArray: true, responseType: 'json' },
      show:    { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' },
      update:  { method: 'PUT', responseType: 'json' },
      delete:  { method: 'DELETE', params: '@id', responseType: 'json' }
    });
})
```

The $resource docs are pretty helpful: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for your answer. I tried this, but the result is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined` in the JS console. Do I need to include into the project some libraries yet?

Comment: hmm, it seems like there is a type somewhere, and the factory is returning undefined. Also you might want to look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167463/angular-js-delete-resource-with-parameter